# configure custom password keyboard with number in jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

we are currently developing mobile application using jquery mobile and phonegap . current requirement is need to display password keyboard with numbers .Is it possible to make android based password keyboard with numuber keyboard in jquery mobile.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: You need to make a custom keyboard? 
If not then try the input type as password and set a pattern attribute as as "[0-9]*"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shinde87sagar/dEfqV/1/  Check this. It has type as password and pattern as number.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shinde87sagar/dEfqV/3/
Do check the comments inline

Comment: @SSS its working in browser but in android device it not showing the numeric keyboard.

Comment: I have written this in comments 
switching to number field will make the keyboard appear as numeric on android mobiles but will lose its password styles

Comment: i was tried with input type as number and added style for the input as -webkit-text-security: disc; it will working fine in android device

Answer (score 1):

create input filed as number and add custom style for the input and you may get number based password keyboard. Its worked in android and iphone.

Html

```
<input id="inputField" name="input" type="number" />
```

Css

```
#inputField{
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<input type="number" />
<input type="tel" />
```

Both of these present the numeric keypad when the input gains focus.

You can't do this with

```
<input type="password" />
```

But you can do this with css:

```
input{
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

More Details [Style Text Like Passwords With CSS](http://www.paulund.co.uk/style-text-like-passwords-with-css)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x7txf5a4/1/)